# wp_register_style not updating on minified css file for wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, minify

I am trying to edit the css for a theme used for a wordpress site however, the minified css file does not seem to be working since many styling elements are missing. I am wondering if there are any issues with regards to how I am linking the file directory in my functions.php file.

```
$template_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
wp_register_style( "styles-fonts", $template_uri."/assets/css/minify/bundle.css", array(), filemtime(get_theme_file_path("/assets/css/minify/bundle.css")), "all" );
    wp_register_style( "styles-main", $template_uri."/assets/css/minify/bundle.css", array(), filemtime(get_theme_file_path("/assets/css/minify/bundle.css")), "all" );
    wp_register_style( "styles-layout", $template_uri."/assets/css/minify/bundle.css", array(), filemtime(get_theme_file_path("/assets/css/minify/bundle.css")), "all" );
    wp_register_style( "styles-navigation", $template_uri."/assets/css/minify/bundle.css", array(), filemtime(get_theme_file_path("/assets/css/minify/bundle.css")), "all" );
    wp_register_style( "styles-marquees", $template_uri."/assets/css/minify/bundle.css", array(), filemtime(get_theme_file_path("/assets/css/minify/bundle.css")), "all" );
    wp_register_style( "styles-images", $template_uri."/assets/css/minify/bundle.css", array(), filemtime(get_theme_file_path("/assets/css/minify/bundle.css")), "all" );
    wp_register_style( "styles-icons", $template_uri."/assets/css/minify/bundle.css", array(), filemtime(get_theme_file_path("/assets/css/minify/bundle.css")), "all" );   
    wp_register_style( "styles-forms-tables", $template_uri."/assets/css/minify/bundle.css", array(), filemtime(get_theme_file_path("/assets/css/minify/bundle.css")), "all" );
    wp_register_style( "styles-animations", $template_uri."/assets/css/minify/bundle.css", array(), filemtime(get_theme_file_path("/assets/css/minify/bundle.css")), "all" );
    wp_register_style( "root", get_stylesheet_uri(), [], filemtime( get_template_directory(). "/style.css"), "all" );
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see above, you are linking the same file `$template_uri."/assets/css/minify/bundle.css` over and over again. Perhaps you meant to change `bundle.css` to match the different file names?

Or if it was meant to be only one file, you don't need to declare it several times with different handles. If that is the case, I'd suggest looking into the compiler/minifier setup to see if all modules are correctly included.

Comment: I meant for there to only be one file. When you mentioned I don't need to declare it multiple times, is there a particular handle I should use in that case. I will also look into the minifier setup however, I believe it should be done correctly through gulp

Comment: If all modules get compiled and minified into the same bundle.css, then you only need to enqueue that file in particular. If the missing styles are spread across other CSS files, you can include these too using the same method. If there are missing modules, you should be able to track this down in the preprocessor/minifier config.